# Relative prefix for django urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

I tried doing something like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('.persons.views',

)
```

in my urls.py file with the directories looking like

```
main folder
\profile
    \person
        urls.py <- this is the file
    urls.py
```

but I got the error "relative imports require the 'package' argument"

I could do 'profiles.persons.view' as the prefix, but I want to try to do a relative prefix like a relative import.  How do I fix this such that the relative prefix works? I'm using django 1.4 and python 2.7.

Comment: What's wrong with being explicit? Relative imports are bad form.